# JdbcTemplate's setFetchSize with RowMapper

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I will be reading lot of data, so I decided to try to lower the memory consumption. I'd like to ask how exactly the [setFetchSize()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize-int-) work (Using SQL Server)? Will it work when I execute

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SQL", new RowMapper<Object>() { ...
```

I'm not really sure if it will not load all data to memory? Will it help to run query method with ResultSetExtractor? Is this setting somehow reliable?

Comment: Eventually all data will be in memory. The `query` method returns a list of all the data that matches. So in the end everything will be in memory.

Comment: So what is the setFetchSizeFor()? Can it be used for some batch processing? Like read 100 rows process them and then read another 100 rows?

Comment: fetchSize is the amount of rows that is fetch in one gone by the jdbc driver. Higher size reduces the amount of round-trips that need to be done by the driver to get all the data at the expense of memory usage, lower size increases the amount of round-trips but uses less memory.

Comment: `jdbcTemplate.query()` just returns List. How do I process only the rows currently fetched by jdbc driver, do I need some callbacks? Is it possible not to return list of all results at once?

Comment: If you only need to process them and not actually return them use a `RowCallbackHandler` instead.

Comment: You mean this variant `public void query(String sql, RowCallbackHandler rch) throws DataAccessException `

Comment: Yes that is the one.